# Expansion in an eval variable

Tags: bash, eval, variable-assignment, command-substitution, brace-expansion

Is it possible to do expansion inside an eval variable?

Example:

```
$ eval VAR=`echo some/path/{file1,file2}`
bash: some/path/file2: No such file or directory
```

I expected the same result as without using eval, that is, setting variable VAR to `some/path/file1 some/path/file2`

Comment: What is a "expansion inside an eval variable"? what is "eval variable"? What expansion do you want to "do"? `I expected the s` But it is not the same, exactly because you are using `eval`. And there is no `A` variable, there is `VAR`.

Comment: eval variable = declaring a variable inside an eval command. I want to expand the curly braces within the variable.

Comment: "VAR=\`echo some/path/{file1,file2}\`" already "expands" it (it does way more than that). You should consider using bash arrays `VAR=(some/path/{file1,file2})` anyway

Comment: This runs ```eval VAR=some/path/file1 some/path/file2```. Thus, it's trying to run `file2` as a command (with VAR in the environment pointing to file1 while that command executes); that's different from putting `file2` into the value of VAR.

Comment: Consider instead `var=( some/path/{file1,file2} )` -- note that that makes var an array, not a string (as an array, you'd expand it as `"${var[@]}"`); also, it doesn't require you to use `eval` at all (and in general, [using `eval` is a serious code smell](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048); bash has a _lot_ of features that exist to give you safe ways to do things you'd have to use `eval` for in a less-capable shell).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was missing the quotes, the command works now. I need to use eval to avoid code repetition in a PKGBUILD file when defining the package() function.

Comment: FYI you almost certainly do NOT need to use `eval` to avoid code repetition. As Charles Duffy noted there are a lot of bash features that handle the things `eval` might normally do for you, but safer and easier to understand. Possibly out of scope for this question but you should consider looking into alternative solutions at some point.

Comment: Also, thanks for the tip with the array expansion.

Comment: [BashFAQ/006](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) explains a lot of techniques for writing non-`eval` code, and [BashFAQ/048](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) explains many of the potential pitfalls of using `eval`.

Comment: @tjm3772 I'm not aware of doing `for I in $_pkgname;do eval "package_$I(){...}";done` without eval (reusing the same function for creating multiple packages)

Comment: @myself600, `for I in $_pkgname` is itself buggy. If your packagenames were _in an array_ you could do `for name in "${pkgnames[@]}"; do`. Yes, you _really do_ need to use eval to define an arbitrarily-named function, but there are tricks one can use to have the shell itself escape the body of that function safely rather than doing that escaping by hand. (Details of what subset of those tricks are applicable would depend on details that are out-of-scope here, but I'd be glad to dive into it if you asked a separate question).

Comment: @Charles Duffy Correct. I wasn't aware of this (or better, recalling this) until you mentioned it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adding quotation marks solved the problem:

```
$ eval VAR=\"`echo some/path/{file1,file2}`\"
```

**Background**: I was trying to define a variable inside eval which contained multiple lines of commands written in a PKGBUILD script, but was advised against doing that. For an appropriate solution, see [Using variables in bash function names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77224251/using-variables-in-bash-function-names).

Comment: To be clear, I don't particularly want the credit, even if I gave you a hint in the right direction -- my advice, which I stand by, was to _not use `eval` at all_ to the extent possible.

Comment: Posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77224251/using-variables-in-bash-function-names