# Using variables in bash function names

Tags: bash, function, global-variables, eval

I'm looking for an alternative to eval when declaring functions that include variables in the name. Function names must have a fixed scheme since they're intended to be used in a PKGBUILD. Example:

```
pkgname=(pkg{1,2,3})
for I in ${pkgname[@]};do eval "package_$I(){
    [ $I = pkg1 ] && echo $I specific stuff
    [ $I = pkg2 ] && echo $I specific stuff
    [ $I = pkg3 ] && echo $I specific stuff
    echo common stuff
    echo common stuff
}";done
package_pkg1
package_pkg2
package_pkg3
```

Expected output:

```
pkg1 specific stuff
common stuff
common stuff
pkg2 specific stuff
common stuff
common stuff
pkg3 specific stuff
common stuff
common stuff
```

Works as needed, except that (from what I was told) eval is not safe to use in this way. What are the alternatives that Bash has to offer?

**Edit**: Fully working PKGBUILD

**Edit 2**: Bash script with output

**Edit 3**: Noted intended use case

Comment: Why not just `$I` as an argument?

Comment: @Diego Torres Milano That doesn't work, unfortunately. It returns ``package_$I': not a valid identifier`.

Comment: Or maybe I misunderstand you. Not sure what you mean by "argument", or specifically, in what way.

Comment: Could I ask for an example that's well-formed enough that we can provide answers with runnable code?

Comment: Added working code

Comment: Please add the output you expect from that command.

Comment: @EdMorton, ...eh. The expectation is that Arch's build tooling will be able to introspect the shell state after evaluating that code and construct packages from it; to test this properly, one needs to be on an Arch system and invoke some magic I no longer recall. Which is to say, just running it _on its own_ doesn't generate output at all. (Do you remember packaging for Arch? I did most if myself when we were working together at Cisco, but it _is_ a thing our team had responsibility for).

Comment: @Ed Morris Not sure how to answer you. This is a complete working script that generates 3 packages as output.

Comment: @myself600, ..._if_ invoked with the right tooling, which the question doesn't currently describe. I've done enough Arch packaging that I recognize what you're doing, but it's reasonable for other folks here not to -- you aren't even tagging it as a makepkg-related question.

Comment: @myself600 (...and really, a [mre] that only folks running a specific distro can test is a lot more particular than something factored to be a generic bash question -- hence it being reasonable to expect there to be tagging or explanation for folks not familiar with that distro and its tooling).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, I remember Arch packaging but I expect the OP could create and post a [mcve] about what they want to do in bash independent of the Arch pkgbuild environment.

Comment: My previous example was a bash script example.

Comment: @myself600, ...yes, it was, but it still didn't provide instructions on how to test whether an answer was correct; which is what I read as being requested here.

Comment: That could be as simple as _"When I run `package_pkg1` after this code is executed, I expect the output lines `pkg1 specific stuff` and `common stuff` to be emitted"_, f/e.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The package() function extracts archives, declares package specific variables that are used in a command, creates/moves folders, etc. I expect it to do something tailored to what function name I run.

Comment: @myself600, yes, I know that. I've been in charge of packaging more than one place, and that's why I added an answer that's appropriate to that purpose. I'm trying to help explain why _other people_ without that background and experience might consider this question a little vague; I don't find it vague myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up moving the code outside of eval:

```
pkgname=(pkg{1,2,3})
_package(){
    [ $pkgname = pkg1 ] && echo pkg1 specific stuff
    [ $pkgname = pkg2 ] && echo pkg2 specific stuff
    [ $pkgname = pkg3 ] && echo pkg3 specific stuff
    echo common stuff
    echo common stuff
}
for i in ${pkgname[@]};do eval "package_$i(){ _package;}";done
```

This however only works inside a PKGBUILD and will not work with Bash, for which you should take a look into @CharlesDuffy's answer.

Comment: As you say -- in a normal shell script without the extra magic makepkg adds, `$pkgname` will evaluate to `${pkgname[0]}`, always referring only to the first package in the list no matter which function is being called.

Answer (score 2):

Why rely on function names instead of arguments?

```
package() {
  local -r pkg="$1"
  case "$pkg" in
    pkg1)
      do_something;;
    pkg2)
      do_something;;
  esac
  do_something
}

...
package pkg1
```

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. The code is coming from a PKGBUILD, hence I have to use a specific function name that is package_PACKAGENAME().

Answer (score 2):

You can use `declare -f` to generate a string with code that defines a function when `eval`ed; modifying that code to update the name means that everything *except* the substring being replaced is guaranteed to be `eval`-safe.

Generating that template might look like:

```
# IMPORTANT: Do not use the word TEMPLATE anywhere inside the body of this function
_package_TEMPLATE() {
  # good form: declare locals so we don't leak variables into global scope
  local current_func
  # inspect current state to find which package we were called for
  current_func=${FUNCNAME#_package_}
  # if we have a helper function for that package, call it
  if [[ $(declare -f "_package_helper_${current_func}" 2>/dev/null) ]]; then
    "_package_helper_${current_func}" "$@" || return
  fi
  # otherwise run the same logic we use for everything we package
  echo "common stuff"
}

# ask the shell itself to serialize package_TEMPLATE with safe escaping
_package_TEMPLATE_def=$(declare -f _package_TEMPLATE)
```

...after which you can define your package-specific content in helpers:

```
# put the content you would otherwise have in your if blocks in helper functions
_package_helper_pkg1() { echo "pkg1-specific code"; }
_package_helper_pkg2() { echo "pkg2-specific code"; }
_package_helper_pkg3() { echo "pkg3-specific code"; }
```

and instantiate templated copies of your function with `eval`, which introspect the name they were called with and look for any like-named helper.

```
# use the template to define the other functions you intend
pkgname=(pkg1 pkg2 pkg3)
for pkg in "${pkgname[@]}"; do
  eval "${_package_TEMPLATE_def//TEMPLATE/$pkg}"
done
```

---

The only strings that are prone to being `eval`ed here without prior eval-safe serialization are the names `pkg1`, `pkg2`, and `pkg3`; since they're hardcoded, they're not at risk.

Comment: Would it be sufficient to declare a function outside eval, then call it? (`eval "package_$I(){ _package;}"`)

Comment: You'd need to refer to a different position in the `FUNCNAME` array, but yes -- refer to `${FUNCNAME[1]}` instead of just `$FUNCNAME` and you could do that.

Comment: (BTW, all-caps variable names -- like `$I` -- are bad form; POSIX specifies that all-caps names are used for variables that reflect or modify the behavior of standard-defined tools, whereas names with at least one lower-case character are reserved for application use and guaranteed not to have unintended effects on the shell itself... at least, not as long as your shell is standard-compliant)